# Populate current user informations in the form fields using Vuejs Laravel Axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to populate current user informations in the form fields using Vuejs Laravel Axios.
In **UserController.vue** I have this code to get auth user information from API :

```
public function profile()
    {
        //
        return auth('api')->user();
    }
```

In routes on **API.php** file I write this :

```
Route::get('profile', 'API\UserController@profile');
```

And in profil.vue page I have theses informations :

```
<script>
 import Form from 'vform';
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
              form: new Form({
              id : '',
              name : '',
              email : '',
              password : '',
              type : '',
              bio : '',
              photo : ''
            })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        created() {
            // affichage des informations de l'utilisateur connecté sur le formulaire
            axios.get("./api/profile")
            .then(({ data }) => (this.form.fill(data)));
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to display current user informations in form fields for exemple :

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nom</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
               <input v-model="form.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nom">
          </div>
</div>
```

I uses Laravel v7.6.2 and vuejs 2

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing us should already work fine.
The fill method from vform will correctly fill the form with the fetched data.

You only need to add the different inputs using the corresponding v-model directive in your form template.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I put the corresponding v-model directive in my form unfortunately I get no data. And when add console.log  
axios.get("./api/profil")
            .then(({ data }) => (console.log(data)));
to see what's happen I get <empty string>
That's look like everything is ok but I get no data.

Comment: In vuejs devtools rooter-view: /profil the form fields return : undefined and I get no error. I use the Laravel lastest version.